# Which bluetooth functions should I use in my UWP app to read in characterstics from my BLE Device

Tags: c#, uwp, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to read temperature characterstic from my BLE device(Blue gecko bgm13p22)
I have tried in the C# Windows BLE code 
this

```
GattReadResult result = await selectedCharacteristic.ReadValueAsync(BluetoothCacheMode.Uncached);//ReadValueAsync-->Performs a Characteristic Value read from the value cache maintained by Windows or retrieve from Windows
```

and this

```
GattReadResult result = await selectedCharacteristic.ReadValueAsync();//ReadValueAsync-->Performs a Characteristic Value read from the value cache maintained by Windows or retrieve from Windows
```

and in package.appxmanifest
I added this

```
 <DeviceCapability Name="bluetooth.genericAttributeProfile">
       <Device Id="any">
          <Function Type="name:healthThermometer" />
       </Device>
    </DeviceCapability>   
  </Capabilities>
```

to read temperature value from BLE device but it still cannot read

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Your code looks correct. Does you characteristic you are trying to read have Read property (by other words: Is it readable)?

Comment: Yes, I am using simplicity studio and in that , in the GATT editor I have set the Read property as True

Comment: Are you able to read the characteristic value using other device, let say your phone?

Comment: yes ,I am able to by Blue gecko app. But I wanted to add one more thing, in my UWP app when I use bluetoothLeDevice.GetGattServicesAsync(BluetoothCacheMode.Cached); then only the connection gets established ,code does not work when I use bluetoothLeDevice.GetGattServicesAsync(BluetoothCacheMode.Uncached);  . Using "Uncached" is creating problems. Can you suggest something ?

Comment: you can see the code here: https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/BluetoothLE/cs/Scenario2_Client.xaml.cs,in this code it uses "Uncached" and says it works but in mine it works with Cached mode

Comment: Would be great to see all your code. It's possible the problem is not in this lines but somewere else. How do you connect to device, is your device paired or not?

Comment: I can mail you my project you can have a look. Problem is in Scenario2_Client.xaml.cs. Can you tell your email ID. BTW my device is paired.

Comment: mike@btframework.com

Answer (score 1):

The Blue Gecko  uses the Bluetooth SIG adopted Health Thermometer service.
The documentation of the SIG states the following:
Source: https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt

> Once configured by the Collector, a Thermometer will typically remain
>   powered off between uses and will only advertise and allow a Collector
>   to connect when the Thermometer has data to send. In this scenario,
>   the Thermometer will enter a GAP Connectable Mode and start
>   advertising when it has data to send to the Collector. The Collector
>   will typically execute a GAP connection establishment procedure such
>   that it is scanning for the Thermometer using a white list. When a
>   connection is established, the Thermometer sends one or more
>   indications or notifications to the Collector. When the data transfer
>   is complete the Thermometer typically terminates the connection.

Where collector is your app, and thermometer your Blue Gecko .

For UWP this means: Listen to the device with the **AdvertisementWatcher** and get the device.
Get the service and connect.
Get the characteristic and set the **ClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptor** to notify.
Implement a Characteristic-value changed method.

This means that the thermometer values are in the notification or you must read the values after the notification has arrived.
If there is no notification there is nothing to read.

I made an example on Github explaining the advertisementwatcher and subscribing tor notifications:https://github.com/GrooverFromHolland/SimpleBleExample_by_Devicename

The example is written for visual studio 2017, but you can read the most important methods and getting an idea
by opening the MainPage.xaml.cs on Github.

You read the temperature in a byte-array, containg a flagsfield(8bits), temperature(4 bytes) and optional timestamp(7 bytes), temptype(8bits)
from https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/viewer?attributeXmlFile=org.bluetooth.characteristic.temperature_measurement.xml
Your appxmanifest must contain:

```
 <Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="internetClient" />
    <DeviceCapability Name="bluetooth" />
</Capabilities>
```

In my example add these lines after:

```
 characteristicFoundMilis = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
                           Debug.WriteLine("Characteristic found in " +
                                          (characteristicFoundMilis - serviceFoundMilis) + " ms");
```

Lines to add:

```
 GattCharacteristicProperties properties = charac.CharacteristicProperties;

                           if (properties.HasFlag(GattCharacteristicProperties.Read))
                           {
                              Debug.WriteLine("This characteristic supports reading from it.");                              
                           }
                           if (properties.HasFlag(GattCharacteristicProperties.Write))
                           {
                              Debug.WriteLine("This characteristic supports writing to it.");                              
                           }
                           if (properties.HasFlag(GattCharacteristicProperties.Notify))
                           {
                              Debug.WriteLine("This characteristic supports subscribing to notifications.");
                           }
                           if (properties.HasFlag(GattCharacteristicProperties.Indicate))
                           {
                              Debug.WriteLine("This characteristic supports subscribing to Indication");
                           }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it seems this is for Windows phone app, I am trying to create a desktop app. On deploying your project it gives error SmartDeviceException - Windows Phone IP over USB Transport (IpOverUsbSvc) is not running. Retry after starting Windows Phone IP over USB Transport (IpOverUsbSvc) from the services management console.

Comment: In the IDE set the platform to x86 and local machine.

Comment: Yeah ok I have download the emulator for it. Another warning is  Certificate file 'SimpleBleExample_by_Devicename_TemporaryKey.pfx' not found. SimpleBleExample_by_Devicename

Comment: I hooked up a dell tablet with Windows 10 on it with my laptop and ran the Simple_bleexample_byDevicename but it says  -->DEP6200: Bootstrapping failed. Device cannot be found. SmartDeviceException - Deployment failed because no device was detected. Make sure a device is connected and powered on.

Comment: It is just a desktop application. to keep it simple the results are shown in the debug output. As I mentioned before: In your visual studio IDE select x86  as your solution platform and set it to run on local machine.
It can be that you have to set the windows version you are using in configuration manager.

Comment: everything runs fine except in the end it gives this error Error registering for notifications: Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.GenericAttributeProfile.GattDeviceServicesResult
The thread 0xa90 has exited with code 0 (0x0).  I have set Notify property as true for the BLE device

Comment: What is the characteristic Uuid you are using? It can be that the characteristic only supports Indicate, if so change  notify  to indicate.

Comment: same error for indications as well-->  Error registering for indications: Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.GenericAttributeProfile.GattDeviceServicesResult. I wrote this code -->  var notifyResult = await charac.WriteClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorAsync(GattClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorValue.Indicate);

Comment: // !!!Your service !!!
         MyService_GUID = new Guid("00001809-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
         //!!!Your characteristic!!!
         MYCharacteristic_GUID = new Guid("00002A1C-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"); I am using "Helath Thermometer" service and "Temperature Measurement" characterstic

Comment: Service and characteristic are OK. I will update my answer with some lines of code that can help you to troubleshoot your problem, I have no idea why you cannot subrcribe to Indications.

Comment: Even I have no clue ,been stuck on this very last step. Can you provide me your email so that I can send my BLE device code where I have done the GATT configuration settings and you can have a look at it\

Comment: It is not a good idea to review your configuration settings,i don`t have a Blue Gecko so it is not possible to check.

Comment: is there any specific version of visual studio that i need? I have vs 17

Comment: 17 is fine, but these list of comments gets too long. if you have problems  with my example open a new issue on Github(select issues new issue)